# How to correctly manage 2 containers of different types in a class?

Tags: c++

I have the following (kinda pseudo) code, which handles 2 containers of 2 different (but somewhat similiar) types, and I hate having these duplications for addition and deletion (and also 2 searching functions in my real code)

```
class PureAbstractClass
{
public:
    virtual char Func() = 0;
}

class PureOpt1 : PureAbstract
{
public:
    virtual int FOption1(A, B, C) = 0; // Notice 'C'
}

class PureOpt2 : PureAbstract
{
public:
    virtual int FOption2(A, B, D) = 0; // Notice 'D'
}

class Handler
{
public:
    void Add(PureOpt1* arg) { v1.add(arg); }
    void Add(PureOpt2* arg) { v2.add(arg); }

    // This is implemented using lambda
    // Sorry for LINQ syntax, lambdas are too long for pseudo code
    void Del1(char c) { arg = v1.find(obj => obj->Func() == c); v1.del(arg); }
    void Del2(char c) { arg = v2.find(obj => obj->Func() == c); v2.del(arg); }

    void Process(ch, A, B, C, D)
    {
        o1 = v1.Find(obj => obj->Func() == ch);

        if( null == o1 )
        {
             o2 = v2.Find(obj => obj->Func() == ch);
             if( null == o2 )
             {
                  DoSomething();
             }
             else
             {
                  o2->FOption2(A, B, D);
             }
        }
        else
        {
             o1->FOption1(A, B, C);
        }

    }

private:
    vector<PureOpt1*> v1;
    vector<PureOpt2*> v2;
}
```

Having `Handler` be a template class is impossible because of `Process()`.

Is there a more correct way to implement this kind of code?

Comment: yes solution is simple, just use `PureAbstractClass` pointer once and keep them all in one vector, that the point of inheritance after all

Comment: @Slava this is impossible - I need to get to POption1 or POption2, this isn't possible through PureAbscractClass* as much as I know

Comment: yes it is possible - worst case use `dynamic_cast<>` but better proper vitual method declared in base class.

Comment: @J.Doe You can do it with a dynamic_cast, but it is ugly.

Comment: @J.Doe If you can use std::variant (C++17) or boost::variant (boost), you can make your PurOpt1 and PureOpt2 into a variant and have Process(A, B, C, D) be a visitor that can be applied to the variant.

Comment: Using dynamic_cast<> might be less ugly than this though. But the function name Process() stinks to me. This feels like an xy problem.

Answer (score 3):

> How to correctly manage 2 containers of different types in a class?

Answer is use only 1 container.

Simplest solution would be to have pure vitual method in base class:

```
class PureAbstractClass
{
public:
    virtual char Func() = 0;
    virtual int FOption(A, B, C, D) = 0; 
}
```

then both children override `FOption()` and ignore parameter they do not need. There could be better solution but you do not provide enough information. Your solution - to keep them in 2 separate containers is probably the worst. As you can see your `solution` conflicts with inheritance (you remove inheritance and make both children independent classes and nothing would change in your code). Alternatively you can use `dynamic_cast`, but using it usually shows bad program design:

```
PureAbstractClass *o = find( ... );
if( !o ) {
   DoSomething();
   return;
}
if( PureOpt1 *po1 = dynamic_cast<PureOpt1 *>( o ) )
     po1->FOption1( A, B, C );
else {
    if( PureOpt2 *po2 = dynamic_cast<PureOpt2 *>( o ) )
        po2->FOption2( A, B, D );
    else
       // something wrong object is not PureOpt1 nor PureOpt2
}
```

Note: it is completely unnecessary for `FOption1()` and `FOption2()` to be virtual in this case. And you should not forget to add virtual destructor to the base class.

Alternatively you may use `boost::variant` and visitor patter, in  this case you do not need inheritance as well but you can make your code generic.

Comment: But what if I had FOption1(A,B,C,D,E) and FOption2(A,B,C,F,G)? Isn't FOption(A,B,C,D,E,F,G) super ugly?

Comment: @J.Doe you already have that ugliness in `void Process(ch, A, B, C, D, E, F, G )` but your question is too abstract, better solution could be found if you show real problem, not imaginary.

Answer (score 0):

If possible have the FOption1/2 be int Func(Data const & data). You then create the data and pass it to it. Data can have the four different pieces of information with C and D being optional. The specific implementation of Func can then process that data as it needs